# Doctrine query syntax error

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-2.1

I have a value in database like  **stackover/'!@#/\;"""'.;\';'./**   with all special char.
Now my problem is that how can I build a query like:

```
$linkName= // getting from db
$sql_sm="SELECT d FROM MyBundle:MyTable d WHERE d.name = '$linkName'";
```

I am getting an error:

```
[Syntax Error] line 0, col 115: Error: Expected end of string, got '\'
```

Comment: have you try mysqli_real_escape_string ?

Comment: @BojanKovacevic He's using doctrine. Moreover, `mysql_*` function are [deprecated](http://bit.ly/phpmsql)

Comment: You should be using doctrine's placeholder support. @Touki, mysqli_* functions are not :)

Comment: @Maerlyn The related comment has been edited

Comment: which placeholder. i am not getting ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [placeholder support of doctrine orm](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#named-and-positional-parameters):

```php
$query = $em->createQuery('SELECT d FROM MyBundle:MyTable d WHERE d.name = ?1');
$query->setParameter(1, $linkName);

$users = $query->getResult();
```

This way you can prevent errors like yours, and what's more important: SQL injection.

Another relevant point in this approach is that the DQL string remains constant. Each time DQL is changed, both the [query cache](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/caching.html#query-cache) and the [result cache](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/caching.html#result-cache) keys change, which basically means that you get a huge performance loss.

Comment: i am getting err   Invalid parameter format, ? given, but :<name> or ?<num> expected.

Comment: No.i have this format...$query = $em->createQuery('SELECT d FROM MyBundle:MyTable d WHERE d.name = ? 1');

Comment: Thanks for the additional info, @Ocramius!